# MongoDB to Jade, through Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am a bit confused about how to best handle data from one source to another through Express. To make this as short as possible, I'll just write a quick example of my "problem". I've tried reading up on this but since this incorporates so many parts I have got "lost in searching" on the way so I figured I (might) be better off just asking on SO.

Anyway, let's say I have a MongoDB document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxYYY"),
    "cheese" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "true",
            "key" : "bleu",
            "table" : "cheeselist"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "true",
            "key" : "gouda",
            "table" : "cheeselist"
        }
    ]
}
```

I "send" this through my controller, where cheese from above is set as an array in my Mongo model:

```
Cheese.find(function (err, docs) {
  var CheeseChunks = [];
  var chunkSize = 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
    CheeseChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  }
  res.render('api/index', {
    url: req.url,
    cheeses: CheeseChunks
  });
})
```

And finally, I use it in my Jade template:

```
each cheeseRow in cheeses
.row: each cheese in cheeseRow
    .col-md-4
        each key in cheese.cheese
            p= JSON.stringify(key)
```

As you can see, right now the only way for me to see the values is to stringify the key, but then I get the whole string and not just the keys value. I am getting confused mostly because I think that I have made a mistake earlier in the workflow which makes this more complicated that it ought to be. Am I right or is there an easy way to solve it in the Jade-template? Or should I perhaps save the string as something other than an array in MongoDB etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give your desired output:

Jade

```
each cheeseRow in cheeses
    .row: each cheese in cheeseRow.cheese
        .col-md-4
             p= cheese.value
        .col-md-4
             p= cheese.key
        .col-md-4
             p= cheese.table
```

Output:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>true</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>bleu</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>cheeselist</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>true</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>gouda</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>cheeselist</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer! It made sense immediately. Why I hit the wall on these sometimes is beyond me...